# Nginx FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"

Tags: php, nginx, nixos

I am using nixos and nginx and i am new to both. right now i am trying to get nginx to work and process a php file.
Whenever i try to open http://[my-example].local/ in the browser it says "File not found".
The nginx-log states

```
Aug 30 19:25:17 nixos nginx[29576]: 2019/08/30 19:25:17 [error] 29579#29579: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/phpfpm/example.sock:", host: "example.local"
```

the nginx part of the configuration parts reads

```
# Enable nginx web server
  services.nginx = {
    enable = true;
    virtualHosts."example.local" = {
      root = "/home/username/PhpstormProjects/wordpress_installations/example/";
      locations = {
        "~ \.php$".extraConfig = ''
        include ${pkgs.nginx}/conf/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/phpfpm/example.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
      '';
       "/".extraConfig = "try_files $uri /index.php?$args ;";
      };
    };
  };
```

and the relevant php part is

```
  # phpfpm
  services.phpfpm.pools.example = {
    listen = "/var/run/phpfpm/example.sock";
    extraConfig = ''
    pm = ondemand
    listen.owner = nginx
    pm.max_children=50;
    user = username
  '';
  };
```

the automatically generated nginx config file is

```
user nginx nginx;
error_log stderr;
daemon off;
events {
}
http {
        include /nix/store/rfs7420034mjxhnwvlyg5cmhddn3q394-nginx-1.14.2/conf/mime.types;
        include /nix/store/rfs7420034mjxhnwvlyg5cmhddn3q394-nginx-1.14.2/conf/fastcgi.conf;
        include /nix/store/rfs7420034mjxhnwvlyg5cmhddn3q394-nginx-1.14.2/conf/uwsgi_params;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA:+AES256:+AES128:+SHA1:!CAMELLIA:!SEED:!3DES:!DES:!RC4:!eNULL;
        # $connection_upgrade is used for websocket proxying
        map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
                default upgrade;
                ''      close;
        }
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        server_tokens off;
        server {
                listen 0.0.0.0:80 ;
                listen [::]:80 ;
                server_name example.local ;
                root /home/username/PhpstormProjects/wordpress_installations/example/;
                location / {
                        try_files $uri /index.php?$args ;
                }
                location ~ .php$ {
                        include /nix/store/rfs7420034mjxhnwvlyg5cmhddn3q394-nginx-1.14.2/conf/fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/phpfpm/example.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I found out something: This configuration works a) for static html files (so its probably not an nginx issue) and b) also for php if i place the index file outside my home directory. but since the php child processes are running under my name (i checked that) i dont know what the problem is!